# How to check whether a control gets a focus or not in android

Tags: android

I have a question that How to check whether the widget having a focus or not. Actually I have a form in which there is a DOB edit text, a user navigates all the edit text boxes with Next action on keyboard and I want when user navigates to DOB field from any of the control then a Calendar Dialog automatically appears, currently what happens is user have to click on edit text then a Calendar Dialog appears, I want whenever DOB field gets a focus then it automatically call the Calendar Dialog.

I have searched regarding the same enough on web but failed to achieve this. Please help me out about this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not

```
if(view.isFocussed) {}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
 1) Create a Handler, as a field in your Activity. Like this:

private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
2) When you create the ListView, add a OnFocusChangeListener, like shown below.

     editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                myHandler.postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        myList.setSelection(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```